# PHP Extension Development

Tags: php, c

I need to create extension on php and add some functionality

lets say we have one function in extension "get_date($key)"
when we call this function in backend will happen this things

1) extension will check if value with key $key is stored in RAM memory if is it return $value if isnt goto 2 step
2) connect to mysql
3) check if in mysql we have value with this key, if we have add to RAM and return if not return false.

my question is how to store value in RAM memory and keep it alive , as you know PHP thread live when somebody is requesting it with SAPI layer in apache or CLI or IIS etc.

Comment: you don't need an extension for that. http://php.net/manual/en/function.shm-attach.php

Comment: ....and APC works too, although that doesn't have a long shelf life. And there's membase. Or use the VFS.....